# Install Elastic Search Failed on Ubuntu while having Java installed

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
# java
if [ -d "$HOME/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_152" ] ; then
    JAVA_HOME="$HOME/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_152"
fi
if [ -d "$HOME/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_152/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_152/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I already have Java installed and if I type `which java` it shows:

`/home/aero/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java`

and if I type `java -version` it shows:

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

but if I want to install elasticsearch by:

`sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-6.6.1.deb`

it shows:

```
(Reading database ... 285478 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack elasticsearch-6.6.1.deb ...
could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH
dpkg: error processing archive elasticsearch-6.6.1.deb (--install):
 new elasticsearch package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 elasticsearch-6.6.1.deb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have Java available when you execute through `sudo`.

```
sudo which java
```

If the above one does not show Java, try the following command:

```
sudo -E which java
```

The `-E` switch is to preserve the environment variables while executing `sudo`.

If the above one works, see if `sudo -E dpkg -i <dpkg_file>` works.

If the above steps does not help, I would recommend you to move the Java install folder outside the user home folder to some common location like `/opt`, see if the binaries have permissions, redefine the `JAVA_HOME` variable and redo the above steps.